# Output binary-data-file compatibilityfor different GFortran versions

Tags: fortran, version, binaryfiles, gfortran

```
MyEnvironment:
Xeon E5-2620 v4 (8 cores) x 2
32GB RAM
CentOS 6.8 (64bit)
GFortran v4.4.7 and v4.9.2
```

Is there any difference between the binary output files generated by the two execution codes compiled by the followings?

- output from execution code by GFortran v4.4.7
- output from execution code by GFortran v4.9.2

There are three execution code compiled using the GFortran :

- metgrid.exe
- ungrib.exe
- geogrid.exe

With GFortran v4.4.7, the ungrib.exe cannot be compiled.
( Error: NAMELIST attribute conflicts with ALLOCATABLE attribute )
With GFortran v4.9.2, the ungrib.exe can be compiled.

With GFortran v4.9.2, the metgrid.exe cannot be compiled.

So I am thinking to use

- metgrid.exe (compiled by v4.4.7)
- ungrib.exe (compiled by v4.9.2)
- geogrid.exe (compiled by v4.4.7)

---

I originally obtained the code with user registration.
The code is not openly available, but the code related to "unformatted" is

```
open(iunit, file=filename, form='unformatted', &
      position='REWIND')
```

and other variants with different `status` or `position`.

The reason why the ungrib.exe cannot be compiled with v4.4.7 is caused by the code (read_namelist.F) for NAMELIST, which is related to the followings

```
  real, dimension(:), allocatable :: new_plvl

  namelist /ungrib/ out_format, &
       ordered_by_date, prefix, &
       add_lvls, new_plvl, interp_type

  allocate(new_plvl(size(new_plvl_in)))
```

It seems that this is related to
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43062

Comment: what do you mean by "binary output files"? this is really unclear what you are asking

Comment: I mean the files opend with "open(..., form="unformatted", ...) to write the data.

Comment: on the same hardware there should be no difference. what problem are you having? whats the bit about namelists have to do with the question?

Comment: On the face of it, the ungrib.exe (with v4.9.2) works with other two execution code (with v4.4.7). However, I will not notice if there's some difference (if any) in the binary files. That's why I asked.
I do not understand your question about "namelists",but The NAMELIST error happneds only with GFortran v4.4.7.

Comment: There should be no difference in the datafile. However the `...` in  `open(..., form="unformatted", ...)` **DO** matter. Please show the complete open line by [edit]ing your question.  Is it someone else's code? Are you interested in fixing the code?

Comment: I am using someone else's code (named WRF). I wonder I can fix the code.

Comment: You could have named the code from the beginning, it is not so uncommon here. So you want to compile parts of the code with different compiler? Good luck with that. You should instead ask the wide WRF xommunity how to compile the whole package in the new gfortran version.

Comment: Of course you could fix the code, ut you would have to aske very differently (make a [mcve] and show the code and complete error messages), but the WRF community probably have encountered that problem before.

Comment: And forgrt gfortran 4.4.7, its WAY too obsolete and buggy.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have checked the http://forum.wrfforum.com/. But up to now, I do not see the similar problem. I will see again. Also I will consider to forget v4.4.7.

Comment: The problem is that what you are linking is a special version for wideland fires based on an old version of WRF. If you just need WRF get a new version. If you need this wildfire version then I don't know but you should look at openwfm.org instead.

Comment: I am sorry for the misleading.

Comment: The point was that you really tried to look there for support, not to you be sorry. There are some requirements on the bottom of http://www.openwfm.org/wiki/How_to_run_WRF-Fire  look for more on that page. Check which exact version you use. Read the README. They should write somewhere which compiler version they used to test it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have installed GFortran v4.9.2 and compiled related softwares (e.g. OpenMPI, NetCDF). It seems that I could compile WRF v3.9 and WPS v3.9 with GFortran v4.9.2.